# Error while testing fabric sample fabcar example

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am getting the following error while running the fabcar sample hyperledger fabric example:

> Error: Cannot find module 'fabric-network'

I have deleted my `node_modules` directory and afterwards ran an `npm install` to get all my project dependencies.

Any ideas on what else to try? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add relevant code samples, the complete error that you're getting.

Comment: Hi @Savitri, did my answer make sense and help?

Comment: I run command as   npm rebuild after the npm install then I got fabric-network module and also other related modules inside  node_modules directory.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `fabric-network` isn't listed as a dependency within your `package.json` file so this dependency isn't installed within your `node_modules` directory when you ran an `npm install`. Maybe you could do the following:

```
npm i --save fabric-network
```

This will install the `fabric-network` module within your `node_modules` directory as well as update your `package.json` file to list this module as a dependency for your project.

Hopefully that helps!